# Nordic Hamstring Curls (without bending arms)

Tags: injury, triceps, hamstring, tendons, rehabilitation

I have quite a unique problem, in that I'm struggling to rehab my lower hamstring tendinopathy because of a tendinopathy in my elbow (tricep).

The physio prescribed me **eccentric / Nordic Hamstring Curls**:

[image]

which seem to do a good job of healing my hamstring... but the problem is that I can't use my arms to stop my fall because of my tricep tendonitis.

My *tricep* tendonitis is healing due to the exercises a different physio gave me a while back, albiet very very slowly. I can't see myself being able to do Nordic hamstring curls properly for a good 4-5 months or so because of my elbow.

I can do Nordic ham curls without the need for a partner because I can wedge my ankles underneath my bed at home... but it's when I need to put my hands down that I struggle.

I've tried putting a bunch of pillows on the floor to cushion my landing without using my arms... but I have to put a **lot** of pillows down and it means I end up doing the exercise with too much range of motion and it makes the injury worse.

I've also tried doing the exercise close to a wall and stopping myself with my hands as I get close to it, but I have to keep my arms straight (to avoid getting elbow pain) which, in turn, puts too much strain on my shoulders.

If anyone has any ideas of how I can cushion my landing without using my arms, and without resulting in additional injuries, I'd be very grateful to hear them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do supine leg curls instead with a TRX/Rings/Slider/Physioball.

I also wonder about your training volume given that you have both a busted hammy and tendonitis.

Comment: Just to add on to this: raise with both legs, lower with one.  This keeps the concentric weight low to protect the injury.